# Field packing to form a single byte

Tags: objective-c, c, hex, bitwise-operators

I'm struggling to learn how to pack four seperate values into a single byte. I'm trying to get a hex output of `0x91` and the binary representation is supposed to be `10010001` but instead I'm getting outputs of: `0x1010001` and `16842753` respectively. Or is there a better way to do this?

```
uint8_t globalColorTableFlag = 1;

uint8_t colorResolution = 001;

uint8_t sortFlag = 0;

uint8_t sizeOfGlobalColorTable = 001;

uint32_t packed = ((globalColorTableFlag << 24) | (colorResolution << 16) | (sortFlag << 8) | (sizeOfGlobalColorTable << 0));

NSLog(@"%d",packed); // Logs 16842753, should be: 10010001
NSLog(@"0x%02X",packed); // Logs 0x1010001, should be: 0x91
```

[image: Packed Field]

Comment: Try NSLog(@"%x", packed) and you will see is happening. The problem is not in the arithmetic, but in your format for NSLog.

Comment: @CharlieBurns I tried that and now I get: `1010001` which is missing a `0` bit

Comment: No, it's not. Where do you expect to see another zero?

Comment: Oh, I see. Leading zeros are stripped.

Comment: I'm so confused on this packing matter.

Comment: you are making a 32-bit integer, why do you expect an 8 bit value? :)

Comment: It gave me a warning saying 10010001 wouldn't fit in an `uint8_t`

Comment: Maybe what you want is (1 << 6)|(1 << 4)|(0 << 2)|(1 << 0), then each value takes two bits. The %x prints hex, not binary. NSLog() may support, %b, I don't know.

Comment: Two of the values occupy three bits and the other two values occupy one bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/* packed starts at 0 */
uint8_t packed = 0;

/* one bit of the flag is kept and shifted to the last position */
packed |= ((globalColorTableFlag & 0x1) << 7);
/* three bits of the resolution are kept and shifted to the fifth position */
packed |= ((colorResolution & 0x7) << 4);
/* one bit of the flag is kept and shifted to the fourth position */
packed |= ((sortFlag & 0x1) << 3);
/* three bits are kept and left in the first position */
packed |= ((sizeOfGlobalColorTable & 0x7) << 0);
```

For an explanation about the relation between hexadecimal and binary digits see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914633/4178025

For bitwise operations see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3427633/4178025

Answer (score 0):

```
packed = ((globalColorTableFlag & 1) << 7) +
    ((colorResolution & 0x7) << 4) +
    ((sortFlag & 1) << 3) +
    ((sizeOfGlobalColorTable & 0x7);
```

Comment: Can you explain what it does?