# Field packing byte returns unexpected results

Tags: objective-c, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I've been experimenting with changing values for some of the bits for field packing a byte, based on my last question: [Field packing to form a single byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836990/field-packing-to-form-a-single-byte)

However, I'm getting unexpected results based on the values. The top code sample gives me an expected output of `0x91`, however if I change `colorResolution` and `sizeOfGlobalColorTable` variables to: `010`, I get an unexpected output of `0x80` which isn't the binary representation of what it should be: `10100010` based from here: http://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/hex-code-table.html. I would expect an output of: `0xA2` for the bottom code sample. What am I missing or not understanding?

This code correctly logs: `0x91`

```
uint8_t screenDescriptorPackedFieldByte = 0;

uint8_t globalColorTableFlag = 1;
uint8_t colorResolution = 001;
uint8_t screenDescriptorSortFlag = 0;
uint8_t sizeOfGlobalColorTable = 001;

screenDescriptorPackedFieldByte |= ((globalColorTableFlag & 0x1) << 7);
screenDescriptorPackedFieldByte |= ((colorResolution & 0x7) << 4);
screenDescriptorPackedFieldByte |= ((screenDescriptorSortFlag & 0x1) << 3);
screenDescriptorPackedFieldByte |= ((sizeOfGlobalColorTable & 0x7) << 0);

NSLog(@"0x%02X",screenDescriptorPackedFieldByte);
```

This code incorrectly logs: `0x80`

```
uint8_t screenDescriptorPackedFieldByte = 0;

uint8_t globalColorTableFlag = 1;
uint8_t colorResolution = 010;
uint8_t screenDescriptorSortFlag = 0;
uint8_t sizeOfGlobalColorTable = 010;

screenDescriptorPackedFieldByte |= ((globalColorTableFlag & 0x1) << 7);
screenDescriptorPackedFieldByte |= ((colorResolution & 0x7) << 4);
screenDescriptorPackedFieldByte |= ((screenDescriptorSortFlag & 0x1) << 3);
screenDescriptorPackedFieldByte |= ((sizeOfGlobalColorTable & 0x7) << 0);

NSLog(@"0x%02X",screenDescriptorPackedFieldByte);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This value is **not binary**. It is [**octal**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_constants.htm).

```
uint8_t sizeOfGlobalColorTable = 010;
```

In `(Objective) C` constants starting from `0` are interpreted as octal values. What you actually write is `b1000 & b0111 = 0`.

It should be:

```
uint8_t sizeOfGlobalColorTable = 0x2;
```

Comment: I do not want hex values as the input, I want to use either 0's or 1's for my flags.

Comment: @aviatorken89 As far as I saw in Google, there are no binary literals in Objective-C, so you will have to deal with it. At lease using Hex will give you working code.

Comment: Or I can just remove the leading zeros and all will be well? That is fine with me if that will make valid bytes.

Comment: @aviatorken89 If you remove leading zeroes value will be *decimal*. In addition if you work with bits, it is much easier to deal with Hex values just because each 4 bits are one Hex symbol (e.g. `b1111` is `0xf`).

Comment: I'm still lost. If I plug in hex values instead of the decimals in the above question sample, the bit shifting messes up the output value now.

Comment: @aviatorken89 I am not sure that I got you now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76201/discussion-between-aviatorken89-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

010 in C is octal (base 8) for the decimal 8.

The leading 0 makes the compiler assume you want an octal value, similar to the usage of the 0x prefix to indicate hexadecimal.

That will (correctly) result in 0 and 0 for lines 2&4 of the bit calculation.
You want to just eliminate the leading 0 of 010 for decimal 10, or if you intended binary 010, 0x10.

Comment: So for flags with leading zeros, I can remove the leading zeros safely?

Comment: In the case of your code, 001 is the same as decimal 1 so yes you can remove the leading zeros.

Comment: I think I just understood your question. If you intend to use hexadecimal for your numbers/flags, use leading 0x and you will not need leading zeros in the hexadecimal value.